# Solving this system of Second ODE

Tags: differential-equations

I’m trying to solve these questions to get a single analytic solution of `x[t]` satisfies all the three equations

```
y[t_] := 3  (x’[t]/x[t] )^2-m,                    (1)
```

```
y[t_] := -2 (x’’[t]/x[t]) - (x’[t]/x[t] )^2,        (2)
```

```
y[t_] := -3 (x’’[t]/x[t] ) -3 (x’[t]/x[t] )^2.       (3)
```

Where m is a constant. The step I made is simplifying by setting  (1)=(2)=(3), and got a single equation:

```
7 (x’[t]/x[t] )^2 + 5 (x’’[t]/x[t]) -m =0
```

Or:

```
x’[t]^2+ 0.7 x’’[t] x[t]- 0.14 m =0
```

How to solve this equation to get an analytic solution of `x[t]` ?
and how to determine the integration constants. The initial conditions are arbitrary, but `m` can't vanish.

Comment: There is does not seem to be an analytical solution for the initial conditions you give. But you can obtain the general solution using `DSolve`. Are you sure the IC's are correct? Notice at $t=0$ you get $0=0.14 m$ since $x(0)=0$ which means $m=0$

Comment: Use any arbitrary initial conditions. Please see the question after the edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we set `x[0]==1`, it seems that `m==0` is the unique solution.

```
y1[t_] = 3 (x'[t]/x[t])^2 - m;
y2[t_] = -2 (x''[t]/x[t]) - (x'[t]/x[t])^2;
y3[t_] = -3 (x''[t]/x[t]) - 3 (x'[t]/x[t])^2;
eqns = Simplify[y1[t] == y2[t] == y3[t]]
sol = DSolve[{(2 x'[t]^2)/x[t] + x''[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 1}, 
  x, t]
Solve[m x[t] == (4 x'[t]^2)/x[t] + 2 x''[t] /. sol[[1]] /. t -> 0]
```

If we set `x[0]==x0`,then

```
Clear[eqns,sol];
y1[t_] = 3 (x'[t]/x[t])^2 - m;
y2[t_] = -2 (x''[t]/x[t]) - (x'[t]/x[t])^2;
y3[t_] = -3 (x''[t]/x[t]) - 3 (x'[t]/x[t])^2;
eqns = Simplify[y1[t] == y2[t] == y3[t]]
sol = DSolve[{eqns[[2]], x[0] == x0, x'[0] == 1}, x, t]
Solve[eqns[[1]] /. sol[[1]] /. t -> 0]
```

The only solution is also `{{m -> 0}, {x0 -> 0}}`.

Comment: What if we consider arbitrary  initial conditions, but `m ` can't vanish.